# Assigning Multiple Numerical Inputs

Tags: java, user-input

I'm attempting to read multiple inputs in one line and assign them to variables. These inputs are EDIT: ints.

I have written some code that does work - but I'm wondering if there's a more streamlined way of doing this:

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x1, y1, x2, y2, distance;
        String[] numbers;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //getting user input
        System.out.print("Enter your first coordinate numbers separated by a space: ");
        numbers = input.nextLine().split(" ");
        x1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        y1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
        System.out.print("Enter your second coordinate numbers separated by a space: ");
        numbers = input.nextLine().split(" ");
        x2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        y2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);

        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2) + Math.pow(y2-y1,2));
        System.out.printf("%.3f", distance);

    }

}
```

As you can see, my method involves taking a string array and assigning the doubles from the array. This works and my program will be accepted. But for my own personal development, I'd like to know if it's possible to have the user enter two (or more) numbers and have them assigned to variables without all the extra steps I took.

Comment: Check the [Scanner API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) - there are various methods to gather user input which doesn't require parsing a String.  Also, the variables are double, but the code uses `Integer.parseInt()`.  Seems like that should be changed to `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: Edited Doubles to Ints - that was my mistake when typing it up.

Comment: if you changed it to int then distance needs to be casted and it will not support this formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
public class InputTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x1, y1, x2, y2, distance;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your first coordinate numbers separated by a space: ");
        x1 = input.nextDouble();
        y1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter your second coordinate numbers separated by a space: ");
        x2 = input.nextDouble();
        y2 = input.nextDouble();
        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
        System.out.printf("%.3f", distance);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand HOW it works, but it works. Thank you. I need to read up on how the input on one line without any further instructions can split up into two variables.

Comment: Basically scanner class will keep asking for inputs till its `nextXXX()` methods are invoked